# What would a "frozen dict" be?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, immutability

- A frozen set is a frozenset.
- A frozen list could be a tuple.
- What would a frozen dict be? An immutable, hashable dict.

I guess it could be something like `collections.namedtuple`, but that is more like a frozen-keys dict (a half-frozen dict). Isn't it?

A "frozendict" should be a frozen dictionary, it should have `keys`, `values`, `get`, etc., and support `in`, `for`, etc.

update :
 * there it is : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0603

Comment: PEP603 is a suggestion and not an implementation: https://peps.python.org/pep-0603/ Furthermore note this in PEP603: "frozenmap has O(log N) complexity"

Comment: **...lolwut?** The `O(log N)` complexity of `frozenmap` is literal insanity. Is that a joke? That's *not* a joke, is it? PEP 603 should be casually dismissed on that basis alone. No further peer review is needed. A [trivial pure-Python `frozendict` implementation that preserves `O(1)` complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62302041/2809027) already exists. I sigh.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Python doesn't have a builtin frozendict type. It turns out this wouldn't be useful too often (though it would still probably be useful more often than `frozenset` is).

The most common reason to want such a type is when memoizing function calls for functions with unknown arguments. The most common solution to store a hashable equivalent of a dict (where the values are hashable) is something like `tuple(sorted(kwargs.items()))`.

This depends on the sorting not being a bit insane. Python cannot positively promise sorting will result in something reasonable here. (But it can't promise much else, so don't sweat it too much.)

---

You could easily enough make some sort of wrapper that works much like a dict. It might look something like

```
import collections

class FrozenDict(collections.Mapping):
    """Don't forget the docstrings!!"""
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._d = dict(*args, **kwargs)
        self._hash = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._d)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._d)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._d[key]

    def __hash__(self):
        # It would have been simpler and maybe more obvious to 
        # use hash(tuple(sorted(self._d.iteritems()))) from this discussion
        # so far, but this solution is O(n). I don't know what kind of 
        # n we are going to run into, but sometimes it's hard to resist the 
        # urge to optimize when it will gain improved algorithmic performance.
        if self._hash is None:
            hash_ = 0
            for pair in self.items():
                hash_ ^= hash(pair)
            self._hash = hash_
        return self._hash
```

It should work great:

```
>>> x = FrozenDict(a=1, b=2)
>>> y = FrozenDict(a=1, b=2)
>>> x is y
False
>>> x == y
True
>>> x == {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
True
>>> d = {x: 'foo'}
>>> d[y]
'foo'
```

Comment: I've never used `collections.Mapping`, but I do see that you have no comparison functions (eq, gt, lt, cmp, ...). Unless they are provided in the `collections.Mapping`, you don't need a hash function. Python will automatically use the object's id as the hash key.

Comment: @wallacoloo, `collections.Mapping` provides `__eq__` and `__ne__` mixins, **which we want**. We also *want* the hash. The defaults of identity comparison for equality and id for hash mean that two `FrozenDict` objects that hold the same data could not be used usefully as dict keys. I added some sample code that shows how this works nicely.

Comment: I don't know what level of thread safety people worry about with this kind of thing, but in that respect your `__hash__` method could be slightly improved.  Simply use a temporary variable when calculating the hash, and only set `self._hash` once you have the final value.  That way another thread getting a hash while the first is calculating will simply do redundant calculation, rather than getting an incorrect value.

Comment: @Jeff As a rule, all code everywhere is not thread-safe, and you should wrap it around some synchronization structures in order to safely use that code. Also, your particular notion of thread safety relies on the atomicity of object attribute assignment, which is far from guaranteed.

Comment: re the sorting... python guarantees the sort order will be consistent, which for these purposes is a good enough definition of 'not insane'. the sort order may not be meaningful (eg alphabetic) but it will be consistent.

Comment: @Anentropic, That's not true at all.

Comment: @DevinJeanpierre Python collection types (dict, list, set, etc are thread-safe in all popular python implementations (CPython, PyPy, IronPython, Jython) also all 4 implementations have atomic object attribute assignment. So yes, theoretically you're correct, but in practice that doesn't matter. Non-thread safe behavior may be surprising on a collections type, and it's easily remedied in this case.

Comment: Be warned: This "FrozenDict" is not necessarily frozen. There is nothing to stop you from putting a mutable list as a value, in which case hashing will throw an error. There's nothing necessarily wrong with that, but users should be aware. Another thing: This hashing algorithm is poorly chosen, very prone to hash collisions. For example {'a':'b'} hashes the same as {'b':'a'} and {'a':1, 'b':2} hashes the same as {'a':2, 'b':1}. Better choice would be self._hash ^= hash((key, value))

Comment: *There is nothing to stop you from putting a mutable list as a value, in which case hashing will throw an error.*  I consider it a feature--what would you prefer instead? The same is true of other immutable collections, like tuples.

Comment: *Another thing: This hashing algorithm is poorly chosen, very prone to hash collisions. For example {'a':'b'} hashes the same as {'b':'a'} and {'a':1, 'b':2} hashes the same as {'a':2, 'b':1}. Better choice would be self._hash ^= hash((key, value))* You're right, and the latter example is particularly compelling. I edited the post.

Comment: If you add a mutable entry in an immutable object, the two possible behaviors are to throw an error on creating the object, or throw an error on hashing the object. Tuples do the latter, frozenset does the former. I definitely think you made a good decision to take the latter approach, all things considered. Nevertheless, I think that people might see that FrozenDict and frozenset have similar names, and jump to a conclusion that they should behave similarly. So I think it is worth warning people about this difference. :-)

Comment: I guess you could alter __getitem__ so it returns a copy of the value in the dict instead of the value itself.

Comment: why put `*args` in `__init__`? doesn't that cause `dict` initialization error?

Comment: @RNA, I pass through to `dict` exactly what you call `FrozenDict` with -- no errors will be caused that wouldn't have been caused by calling `dict`.

Comment: I know this is a niche use, but I have found tremendous use for frozensets in doing discrete mathematics, caching functions on set-families. They provide the fast lookup, as compared with scanning a long tuple, or even bisection of a sorted tuple. They are one of my favorite things in the language.

Comment: Why not just extend `dict` and override `__setitem__` to raise an error? Also add `__hash__` of course.

Comment: I've personally found that frozensets are useful for describing undirected edges in a graph. Without them I would have to constantly check order with tuples.

Comment: I would disagree that frozendict wouldn't be useful too often. We switched a lot of places to use frozendicts and it removes a lot of bugs. For example, [default argument bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526465/best-practice-for-setting-the-default-value-of-a-parameter-thats-supposed-to-be) could be nicely resolved with `def function(defaults=frozendict())`. Also thisngs like algorithm parametrizations, sending dicts between system components, multithreading without locks etc. cane be nicely and safely done with frozendicts.

Comment: For those who need performant `frozendict` there is [project](https://pypi.org/project/frozenmap/). It's version of `FrozenDict` implented with the help of Cython.

Comment: @MikeGraham "Re wouldn't be useful too often" - au contraire, it is very useful in data science, for example group by fragments of JSON data. I use the analogous functionality in Wolfram Language, whose dictionaries are built using tries so keys can be mutable.

Comment: immutability shines in clojure. Too bad it's not supported in standard in Python.

Comment: @Devin Jeanpierre: An exception to that rule is that you can assume that immutable data structures *are* thread safe, because the usual thread safety risk – that one thread changes it while another is reading it – is not possible. Often, that is the whole reason for using immutable data structures in the first place. Given that the point of this `FrozenDict` is to be immutable, it certainly should be thread safe. In my view, the best fix would be to compute the hash on construction.

Comment: @ArthurTacca Fair enough, I made the implementation thread safe.

Comment: For compatibility with python 3, `self.iteritems()` should be replaced with `self.items()`

Comment: Your hash function is bugged. This is my py implementation: https://github.com/Marco-Sulla/python-frozendict/blob/800d32b71d9ba4b15dfd55c7092f047fbfe30068/frozendict/core.py#L73  PS: I'm the current maintainer of frozendict, that includes also a C extension, so it's __really__ immutable: https://pypi.org/project/frozendict/

Comment: Instead of `tuple(sorted())`, could you use `frozenset()`?

Comment: There seems to be a potentially abandoned pep for this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0603/

Comment: Not really immutable, since you can access `_d`. `frozendict` Pypi package uses now a C extension, so it's really immutable (I'm the new maintainer)

Answer (score 103):

Curiously, although we have the seldom useful `frozenset`, there's still no frozen mapping. The idea was rejected in [PEP 416 -- Add a frozendict builtin type](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0416/). This idea may be revisited in a later Python release, see [PEP 603 -- Adding a frozenmap type to collections](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0603/).

So the Python 2 solution to this:

```
def foo(config={'a': 1}):
    ...
```

Still seems to be the usual:

```
def foo(config=None):
    if config is None:
        config = {'a': 1}  # default config
    ...
```

In Python 3 you have the option of [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType):

```
from types import MappingProxyType

default_config = {'a': 1}
DEFAULTS = MappingProxyType(default_config)

def foo(config=DEFAULTS):
    ...
```

Now the default config *can* be updated dynamically, but remain immutable where you want it to be immutable by passing around the proxy instead.

So changes in the `default_config` will update `DEFAULTS` as expected, but you can't write to the mapping proxy object itself.

Admittedly it's not really the same thing as an "immutable, hashable dict", but it might be a decent substitute for some use cases of a frozendict.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to store the proxy in a module variable? Why not just `def foo(config=MappingProxyType({'a': 1})):`? Your example still allows global modification through `default_config`, too.

Answer (score 27):

Assuming the keys and values of the dictionary are themselves immutable (e.g. strings) then:

```
>>> d
{'forever': 'atones', 'minks': 'cards', 'overhands': 'warranted', 
 'hardhearted': 'tartly', 'gradations': 'snorkeled'}
>>> t = tuple((k, d[k]) for k in sorted(d.keys()))
>>> hash(t)
1524953596
```

Comment: This is a good, canonical, immutable representation of a dict (barring insane comparison behavior messing up the sort).

Comment: @devin: agreed in full, but I'll let my post stand as an example that there's often an even better way.

Comment: Even better would be to put it in a frozenset, which does not require the keys or values to have a consistent ordering defined.

Comment: Only one problem with this: you no longer have a mapping. That would be the whole point of having the frozen dict in the first place.

Comment: This method is really nice when going back to a dict. simply `dict(t)`

Comment: Depending on exactly what you're doing, the sorting may be unnecessary.

Comment: Good for @functools.lru_cache.  Neat thing is a function can just `dict(x)` to get a mapping back, whether x is already a `dict` or this thing above.

Answer (score 24):

There is no `fronzedict`, but you can use [`MappingProxyType`](https://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType) that was added to the standard library with Python 3.3:

```
>>> from types import MappingProxyType
>>> foo = MappingProxyType({'a': 1})
>>> foo
mappingproxy({'a': 1})
>>> foo['a'] = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment
>>> foo
mappingproxy({'a': 1})
```

Comment: with the caveat: `TypeError: can't pickle mappingproxy objects`

Comment: Issue with this is `MappingProxyType` is still unhashable.

Answer (score 19):

Install [frozendict](https://pypi.org/project/frozendict/)

```
pip install frozendict
```

Use it!

```
from frozendict import frozendict

def smth(param = frozendict({})):
    pass
```

Comment: This is also nice because it is hashable and one can inherit from frozendict as a base class. Neither of those is possible if you use MappingProxyType.

Answer (score 12):

I think of frozendict everytime I write a function like this:

```
def do_something(blah, optional_dict_parm=None):
    if optional_dict_parm is None:
        optional_dict_parm = {}
```

Comment: Easier formulation: `optional_dict_parm = optional_dict_parm or {}`

Comment: In this case you can use [`types.MappingProxyType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType)`({})` as default value for argument.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus could you write that up as an answer?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: it seems like [@wim already did that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30638022/3821804).

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus yes, it came up [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30637306/3001761)!

Comment: @Emmanuel You want the `is None` check to catch falsy arguments, like for example `MappingProxyType({})`, or if someone made a typo, `0` for example.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the code I've been using.  I subclassed frozenset.  The advantages of this are the following.

1. This is a truly immutable object.  No relying on the good behavior of future users and developers.
2. It's easy to convert back and forth between a regular dictionary and a frozen dictionary.  FrozenDict(orig_dict) --> frozen dictionary.  dict(frozen_dict) --> regular dict.

Update Jan 21 2015:  The original piece of code I posted in 2014 used a for-loop to find a key that matched.  That was incredibly slow.  Now I've put together an implementation which takes advantage of frozenset's hashing features.  Key-value pairs are stored in special containers where the `__hash__` and `__eq__` functions are based on the key only.  This code has also been formally unit-tested, unlike what I posted here in August 2014.

MIT-style license.

```
if 3 / 2 == 1:
    version = 2
elif 3 / 2 == 1.5:
    version = 3

def col(i):
    ''' For binding named attributes to spots inside subclasses of tuple.'''
    g = tuple.__getitem__
    @property
    def _col(self):
        return g(self,i)
    return _col

class Item(tuple):
    ''' Designed for storing key-value pairs inside
        a FrozenDict, which itself is a subclass of frozenset.
        The __hash__ is overloaded to return the hash of only the key.
        __eq__ is overloaded so that normally it only checks whether the Item's
        key is equal to the other object, HOWEVER, if the other object itself
        is an instance of Item, it checks BOTH the key and value for equality.

        WARNING: Do not use this class for any purpose other than to contain
        key value pairs inside FrozenDict!!!!

        The __eq__ operator is overloaded in such a way that it violates a
        fundamental property of mathematics. That property, which says that
        a == b and b == c implies a == c, does not hold for this object.
        Here's a demonstration:
            [in]  >>> x = Item(('a',4))
            [in]  >>> y = Item(('a',5))
            [in]  >>> hash('a')
            [out] >>> 194817700
            [in]  >>> hash(x)
            [out] >>> 194817700
            [in]  >>> hash(y)
            [out] >>> 194817700
            [in]  >>> 'a' == x
            [out] >>> True
            [in]  >>> 'a' == y
            [out] >>> True
            [in]  >>> x == y
            [out] >>> False
    '''

    __slots__ = ()
    key, value = col(0), col(1)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.key)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Item):
            return tuple.__eq__(self, other)
        return self.key == other
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%r: %r' % self
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Item((%r, %r))' % self

class FrozenDict(frozenset):
    ''' Behaves in most ways like a regular dictionary, except that it's immutable.
        It differs from other implementations because it doesn't subclass "dict".
        Instead it subclasses "frozenset" which guarantees immutability.
        FrozenDict instances are created with the same arguments used to initialize
        regular dictionaries, and has all the same methods.
            [in]  >>> f = FrozenDict(x=3,y=4,z=5)
            [in]  >>> f['x']
            [out] >>> 3
            [in]  >>> f['a'] = 0
            [out] >>> TypeError: 'FrozenDict' object does not support item assignment

        FrozenDict can accept un-hashable values, but FrozenDict is only hashable if its values are hashable.
            [in]  >>> f = FrozenDict(x=3,y=4,z=5)
            [in]  >>> hash(f)
            [out] >>> 646626455
            [in]  >>> g = FrozenDict(x=3,y=4,z=[])
            [in]  >>> hash(g)
            [out] >>> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

        FrozenDict interacts with dictionary objects as though it were a dict itself.
            [in]  >>> original = dict(x=3,y=4,z=5)
            [in]  >>> frozen = FrozenDict(x=3,y=4,z=5)
            [in]  >>> original == frozen
            [out] >>> True

        FrozenDict supports bi-directional conversions with regular dictionaries.
            [in]  >>> original = {'x': 3, 'y': 4, 'z': 5}
            [in]  >>> FrozenDict(original)
            [out] >>> FrozenDict({'x': 3, 'y': 4, 'z': 5})
            [in]  >>> dict(FrozenDict(original))
            [out] >>> {'x': 3, 'y': 4, 'z': 5}   '''

    __slots__ = ()
    def __new__(cls, orig={}, **kw):
        if kw:
            d = dict(orig, **kw)
            items = map(Item, d.items())
        else:
            try:
                items = map(Item, orig.items())
            except AttributeError:
                items = map(Item, orig)
        return frozenset.__new__(cls, items)

    def __repr__(self):
        cls = self.__class__.__name__
        items = frozenset.__iter__(self)
        _repr = ', '.join(map(str,items))
        return '%s({%s})' % (cls, _repr)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self:
            raise KeyError(key)
        diff = self.difference
        item = diff(diff({key}))
        key, value = set(item).pop()
        return value

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        if key not in self:
            return default
        return self[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        items = frozenset.__iter__(self)
        return map(lambda i: i.key, items)

    def keys(self):
        items = frozenset.__iter__(self)
        return map(lambda i: i.key, items)

    def values(self):
        items = frozenset.__iter__(self)
        return map(lambda i: i.value, items)

    def items(self):
        items = frozenset.__iter__(self)
        return map(tuple, items)

    def copy(self):
        cls = self.__class__
        items = frozenset.copy(self)
        dupl = frozenset.__new__(cls, items)
        return dupl

    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(cls, keys, value):
        d = dict.fromkeys(keys,value)
        return cls(d)

    def __hash__(self):
        kv = tuple.__hash__
        items = frozenset.__iter__(self)
        return hash(frozenset(map(kv, items)))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, FrozenDict):
            try:
                other = FrozenDict(other)
            except Exception:
                return False
        return frozenset.__eq__(self, other)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)


if version == 2:
    #Here are the Python2 modifications
    class Python2(FrozenDict):
        def __iter__(self):
            items = frozenset.__iter__(self)
            for i in items:
                yield i.key

        def iterkeys(self):
            items = frozenset.__iter__(self)
            for i in items:
                yield i.key

        def itervalues(self):
            items = frozenset.__iter__(self)
            for i in items:
                yield i.value

        def iteritems(self):
            items = frozenset.__iter__(self)
            for i in items:
                yield (i.key, i.value)

        def has_key(self, key):
            return key in self

        def viewkeys(self):
            return dict(self).viewkeys()

        def viewvalues(self):
            return dict(self).viewvalues()

        def viewitems(self):
            return dict(self).viewitems()

    #If this is Python2, rebuild the class
    #from scratch rather than use a subclass
    py3 = FrozenDict.__dict__
    py3 = {k: py3[k] for k in py3}
    py2 = {}
    py2.update(py3)
    dct = Python2.__dict__
    py2.update({k: dct[k] for k in dct})

    FrozenDict = type('FrozenDict', (frozenset,), py2)
```

Comment: Note that you have also licensed it under CC BY-SA 3.0, by posting it here. At least that's the [prevalent view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109787/247924). I guess the legal basis for that is agreeing to some T&Cs when you first signed up.

Comment: I broke my brain trying to think of a way to look up the key hash without a dict. Redefining the hash of the `Item` to be the hash of the key is a neat hack!

Comment: Unfortunately, the run time of `diff(diff({key}))` is still linear in the size of the FrozenDict, while regular dict access time is constant in the average case.

Answer (score 8):

## Subclassing `dict`

i see this pattern in the wild (github) and wanted to mention it:

```
class FrozenDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._hash = None
        super(FrozenDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __hash__(self):
        if self._hash is None:
            self._hash = hash(tuple(sorted(self.items())))  # iteritems() on py2
        return self._hash

    def _immutable(self, *args, **kws):
        raise TypeError('cannot change object - object is immutable')

    # makes (deep)copy alot more efficient
    def __copy__(self):
        return self

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo=None):
        if memo is not None:
            memo[id(self)] = self
        return self

    __setitem__ = _immutable
    __delitem__ = _immutable
    pop = _immutable
    popitem = _immutable
    clear = _immutable
    update = _immutable
    setdefault = _immutable
```

example usage:

```
d1 = FrozenDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
d2 = FrozenDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
d1.keys() 
assert isinstance(d1, dict)
assert len(set([d1, d2])) == 1  # hashable
```

**Pros**

- support for `get()`, `keys()`, `items()` (`iteritems()` on py2) and all the goodies from `dict` out of the box without explicitly implementing them
- uses internally `dict` which means performance (`dict` is written in c in CPython)
- elegant simple and no black magic
- `isinstance(my_frozen_dict, dict)` returns True - although python encourages [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) many packages uses `isinstance()`, this can save many tweaks and customizations

**Cons**

- any subclass can override this or access it internally (you cant really 100% protect something in python, you should trust your users and provide good documentation).
- if you care for speed, you might want to make `__hash__` a bit faster.

Comment: I did a speed comparison in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62302041/929999) and it turns out, overriding `__setitem__` and inheriting `dict` is insanely fast compared to many alternatives.

Comment: You can inherit from collections.UserDict. It was intended for that purpose, normal dict has lots of flaws when subclassed

Answer (score 6):

You may use [`frozendict`](http://utilspie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#frozendict) from [`utilspie`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/utilspie) package as:

```
>>> from utilspie.collectionsutils import frozendict

>>> my_dict = frozendict({1: 3, 4: 5})
>>> my_dict  # object of `frozendict` type
frozendict({1: 3, 4: 5})

# Hashable
>>> {my_dict: 4}
{frozendict({1: 3, 4: 5}): 4}

# Immutable
>>> my_dict[1] = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mquadri/workspace/utilspie/utilspie/collectionsutils/collections_utils.py", line 44, in __setitem__
    self.__setitem__.__name__, type(self).__name__))
AttributeError: You can not call '__setitem__()' for 'frozendict' object
```

---

As per the [document](http://utilspie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#frozendict):

> **frozendict(dict_obj)**: Accepts obj of dict type and returns a hashable and immutable dict

Answer (score 5):

The main disadvantage of `namedtuple` is that it needs to be specified before it is used, so it's less convenient for single-use cases.

However, there is a practical workaround that can be used to handle many such cases. Let's say that you want to have an immutable equivalent of the following dict:

```
MY_CONSTANT = {
    'something': 123,
    'something_else': 456
}
```

This can be emulated like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

MY_CONSTANT = namedtuple('MyConstant', 'something something_else')(123, 456)
```

It's even possible to write an auxiliary function to automate this:

```
def freeze_dict(data):
    from collections import namedtuple
    keys = sorted(data.keys())
    frozen_type = namedtuple(''.join(keys), keys)
    return frozen_type(**data)

a = {'foo':'bar', 'x':'y'}
fa = freeze_dict(data)
assert a['foo'] == fa.foo
```

Of course this works only for flat dicts, but it shouldn't be too difficult to implement a recursive version.

Comment: Same problem as with the other tuple answer: you have to do `getattr(fa, x)` instead of `fa[x]`, no `keys` method at your finger tips, and all the other reasons a mapping can be desirable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is my second answer, but it is a completely different approach.  The first implementation was in pure python.  This one is in Cython.  If you know how to use and compile Cython modules, this is just as fast as a regular dictionary.  Roughly .04 to .06 micro-sec to retrieve a single value.

This is the file "frozen_dict.pyx"

```
import cython
from collections import Mapping

cdef class dict_wrapper:
    cdef object d
    cdef int h

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.d = dict(*args, **kw)
        self.h = -1

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.d)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.d)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.d[key]

    def __hash__(self):
        if self.h == -1:
            self.h = hash(frozenset(self.d.iteritems()))
        return self.h

class FrozenDict(dict_wrapper, Mapping):
    def __repr__(self):
        c = type(self).__name__
        r = ', '.join('%r: %r' % (k,self[k]) for k in self)
        return '%s({%s})' % (c, r)

__all__ = ['FrozenDict']
```

Here's the file "setup.py"

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize('frozen_dict.pyx')
)
```

If you have Cython installed, save the two files above into the same directory.  Move to that directory in the command line.

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
python setup.py install
```

And you should be done.

Answer (score 1):

[freeze](https://github.com/Lightricks/freeze) implements frozen collections (dict, list and set) that are hashable, type-hinted and will recursively freeze the data you give them (when possible) for you.

```sh
pip install frz
```

Usage:

```py
from freeze import FDict

a_mutable_dict = {
    "list": [1, 2],
    "set": {3, 4},
}

a_frozen_dict = FDict(a_mutable_dict)

print(repr(a_frozen_dict)) 
# FDict: {'list': FList: (1, 2), 'set': FSet: {3, 4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

An earlier answer by @msw suggested a tuple. This is an easier way of creating a tuple.

```py
mydata={"foo":"bar","x":"y"}
mydict[tuple(mydata.items())] = True
```

Answer (score -1):

I needed to access fixed keys for something at one point for something that was a sort of globally-constanty kind of thing and I settled on something like this:

```
class MyFrozenDict:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'mykey1':
            return 0
        if key == 'mykey2':
            return "another value"
        raise KeyError(key)
```

Use it like

```
a = MyFrozenDict()
print(a['mykey1'])
```

WARNING: I don't recommend this for most use cases as it makes some pretty severe tradeoffs.

Comment: The following would be equal in power without the performance scarifices. However, this is just a simplification of the accepted answer...
```
class FrozenDict:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self._data = data
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self._data[key]
```

Comment: @Yuval that answer is not equivalent. For starters the api is different as it needs data to init. This also implies it is no longer globally-accessible. Furthermore, if _data is mutated, your return value changes. I am aware that there are significant tradeoffs - like I said, I don't recommend this for most use cases.