# How to use a dictionary as key for a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, reference, dictionary

All -

I have a very basic question today ... but it has been preventing me from moving on productively in my programming, so I am posting it here.

I want to create a dictionary that takes a dictionary as a key. Presumably I can only pass a reference to the dictionary as key ... only I don't know how to do that in Python. Here is a toy reduction of what I am trying to do:

```
def test( dict ):
    a={}
    b={1:1}
    a[ dict ] = b
    return a

a = {0:0}
print test( a )
```

I would like b to be a dictionary of the form { {0:0} : {1:1} }.

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Kind regards -

Pat

Comment: can you explain the usecase? why would you need a dictionary as a key?

Comment: Why don't you use a list or tuple?

Comment: @Rapptz -- Can't use a `list` either.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703599/what-would-be-a-frozen-dict

Comment: Regarding the usecase: My dictionaries are feature vectors and I want to store the distance between two feature vectors in a dictionary:
    distance[vector1][vector2]= ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys for dictionaries *must* be hashable items; unfortunately, dictionaries themselves are not hashable (they are mutable, which disqualifies them from being hashable).

Use their item list, converted to a sorted tuple, instead:

```
a[tuple(sorted(dct.items()))] = b
```

Mutable objects are not hashable because they can be changed in-place, making later key-lookups fail. What would the expected outcome be if you added or removed items from the dictionary you used as the key, for example?

Comment: Sadly, this won't work exactly as required, because the order of `dct.items()` might vary, leading to index errors.

Comment: @nightcracker: in most cases, the order of the same set of key/value pairs would be returned in the same order. If you insert, then remove a lot of keys, then insert again, you *could* loose that ordering though, so I'll add some sorting.

Comment: Sorting is an inadequate solution for this, considering it's `O(n log n)` complexity (while hashing each element requires only `O(n)`), as well as requiring the elements be sortable (which is an unnecessary requirement in addition to being hashable). See the frozendict implementation I link in my answer.

Comment: @nightcracker: Generally speaking using `dict` as a key is suspect in the first place and needs some rethinking. The rest of my answer (why doesn't this work) is more important to larger picture in any case.

Comment: @Martin Pieters: Why is the use of dict as a key suspect in the first place? The usecase outlined in my comment above is a perfectly valid usecase in my view. Other programming languages (e.g., Perl) let you do this without any hassle.

Comment: @Pat: Sounds like you want to create a Vector class instead (with `__hash__()` and `__eq__` methods).

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries can only use *hashable* objects as keys, which means they must be *immutable*. The default dictionary isn't either, so that won't work. You can try a [frozendict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2704866/565635) though.

Answer (score 1):

[Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys):

> To be used as a dictionary key, an object must support the hash function (e.g. through __hash__), equality comparison (e.g. through __eq__ or __cmp__), and must satisfy the correctness condition above.

So trying this out:

```
a = {0: 0}
hash(a)
```

yields the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    hash(a)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

basically just confirming what mgilson already said. You are out of luck as far as using a dictionary (or a list, etc) as a dictionary key.

Answer (score 1):

a dict can't be used as a key as it is unhashable.

```
hash(a)
```

so i would rethink your problem or if you really need to hash a dict you could represent is a a string , or tuples and hash by that:

```
hash(tuple(dict.items()))
hash(''.join(["%s%s" %(k, v) for k,v in dict.items()]))
```

Comment: While both problems can be worked around, as written: (1) `dict.items()` isn't hashable either, and (2) that string will give the same results for {1:23} as for {12:3}..

Comment: I think you want `tuple(dict.items())`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who replied. I know this was a fairly basic question and all the infos on hashability and mutability is much appreciated.

I will indeed pursue the approach of mapping an input vector (a dictionary itself) to the sorted tuple of its items. This characterises a given dictionary unambiguously and is a  hashable data structure such that it can be used as a dictionary key.

```
def get_key( dict1, dict2 ):

    list = dict1.items() + dict2.items()
    list.sort()
    return tuple( list )

a,b = {'feature1':0}, {'feature1':1}
print get_key( a, b )
```