# Immutable Dictionary with key-object pairs Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, frozenset

I have a dictionary filled with key-object pairs. I want to make the dictionary immutable and I thought the best/easiest way is to cast it to a frozenset but `frozenset(dict)` and also `tuple(dict)` only stores the keys.

Using `frozenset(dict.items())` I seem to get a frozenset with the key-object pairs but I don't know how to retrieve the values/keys.

I have the following code which works, as long as "__obfuscators" is a dictionary

```
def obfuscate_value(self, key, value):
    obfuscator = self.__obfuscators.get(key)
    if obfuscator is not None:
        return obfuscator.obfuscate_value(value)
    else:
        return value
```

I tried this in an attempt to get it working with the frozen set:

```
def obfuscate_value(self, key, value):
    try:
        obfuscator = self.__obfuscators[key]
    except:
        return value
    return obfuscator.obfuscate_value(value)
```

but this gives that `frozenset does not have \__getitem__`
and `self.__obfuscators.__getattribute__(key)` always says it does not have the attribute (because I assume this searches for a function named key)
Is there a better way to make the dictionary immutable or how can I retrieve the object depending on the key?

Edit:
I ended up casting the dict to a tuple using `tuple(obfuscator.items())`
and then wrote my own find value function:

```
def find_obfuscator(self, key):
    for item in self.__obfuscators:
        x, y = item
        if self.case_insensitive:
            if x.lower() == key.lower():
                return y
        else:
            if x == key:
                return y
```

I would like to thank everyone for their efforts and input.

Comment: what about subclassing`collections.Mapping` or using a `Mappingproxy`. As far as I know both are immutable (for a given value of immutable).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would a "frozen dict" be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703599/what-would-a-frozen-dict-be)

Answer (score 3):

You can create an immutable view of a dictionary using [`types.MappingProxyType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType):

```
from types import MappingProxyType
d = { 'a': 1 }
fd = MappingProxyType(d)
fd['a']
#output:
1

fd['a'] = 2
#output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment
```

notice that you can still change the vaule object, so:

```
d = { 'a': [1] }
fd = MappingProxyType(d)
fd['a'].append(2)
fd['a']
#output:
[1,2]
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I could think of to achieve what you want was to subclass the standard `dict` type and overwrite its `__setitem__` method:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        raise NotImplementedError("This is a frozen dictionary")
```

This allows you to create dictionaries that cannot thereafter be changed by item assignment:

```
d = MyDict({1: 2, 3: 4})
```

or, equivalently:

```
d = MyDict([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
```

The dict then prints out just like a standard dict:

```
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

But when you try to change a value (or add a new one):

```
d[1] = 15
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-a22420992053> in <module>()
----> 1 d[1] = 34

<ipython-input-18-03f266502231> in __setitem__(self, key, value)
      1 class MyDict(dict):
      2     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
----> 3         raise NotImplementedError("This is a frozen dictionary")

NotImplementedError: This is a frozen dictionary
```

Note that this isn't fully immutable, however:

```
d.update({1:17})
```

for example, will update it, but this solution might be good enough - it depends on the broader requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a wrapper class that takes a dictionary and has a get item function but no set item.  You'd need to add a few things for thread safety and hashing maybe but the basic class wouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: I did think about this but I hoped there would be an easier/faster solution than making an own custom dictionary class. Especially since I seemed like I was so close now because I have a frozenset with key-object pairs, but I just cannot access them or at least I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention `tuple(dict)` in your original post, probably the simplest solution to achieve what you want might simply be:

```
tuple(dict.items())
```

Comment: with this option I still face the same problem as in the `frozenset(dict.items())`. How can I access the value, based on the key?

Comment: when thinking about this option again I realized it would probably be the easiers solution, if I made my own search function since all the other options are not more simple

Answer (score 0):

You need a `dict` that is capable of freezing? You can simply make one:

```
class FrozenDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._frozen = False
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def freeze(self):
        self._frozen = True
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if (self._frozen):
            raise TypeError("Attempted assignment to a frozen dict")
        else:
            return dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

a = FrozenDict({7:8})
a[5] = 6
print(a)
a.freeze()
a[3] = 2 # raises TypeError
```

It will behave exactly like usual `dict` until you call `.freeze()`. Then it's frozen.