# python's ast.literal_eval() changes my dictionary sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am designing a dictionary from a string, but I have noticed that after using 'ast.literal_eval()' on python 2.7, my dictionary sequence changes. The good thing is that the values designated to the keys follow suit. I just wanted to know why it does this. Here is a snippet of my code that should be able to run:

```
import ast

Medication = ["{'A': 3, 'B': 10, 'C': 0, 'D': 3}"]
print "Medication before ast.literal_eval: ", Medication[0]
print ""
dictionaryDose = ast.literal_eval(Medication[0])
print "Medication after ast.literal_eval: ", Medication[0]
print ""
print "DictionaryDose: ", dictionaryDose
```

Here is the output:

> Medication before ast.literal_eval:  {'A': 3, 'B': 10, 'C': 0, 'D': 3}
>
> Medication after ast.literal_eval:  {'A': 3, 'B': 10, 'C': 0, 'D': 3}
>
> DictionaryDose:  {'A': 3, 'C': 0, 'B': 10, 'D': 3}

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered containers. You should not rely on them being in any particular order.

Comment: If order is important, you can check the answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703599/what-would-a-frozen-dict-be

Comment: If you don't care about the order except when printed on screen, try the pretty print `pprint` module.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are unordered. If you want to keep the order you can use the  `json` module and `collections.OrderedDict`. You will have to convert single quotes to double quotes before you do this though:

```
Medication = "{'A': 3, 'B': 10, 'C': 0, 'D': 3}"
Medication = Medication.replace("'", '"')

print json.JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict).decode(Medication)
```

Output: 
`OrderedDict([(u'A', 3), (u'B', 10), (u'C', 0), (u'D', 3)])`

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.OrderedDict`. Just note for python 2.7, use `.iteritems()` instead of `.items()`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import ast

Medication = ["{'A': 3, 'B': 10, 'C': 0, 'D': 3}"]
print("Medication before ast.literal_eval: ", Medication[0])
print("")
dictionaryDose = ast.literal_eval(Medication[0])
print("Medication after ast.literal_eval: ", Medication[0])
dictionaryDoseOrdered = OrderedDict([(k,v) for k,v in dictionaryDose.items()])
print("")
print("DictionaryDose: ", dictionaryDoseOrdered)
```