# Avoiding Default Argument Value is Mutable Warning (PyCharm)

Tags: python, pycharm

**Code:**

```py
def evaluate_fruit(fruits):
    for fruit in fruits:
        if fruit == "Apple":
            print("Good choice!")
        else:
            print("Meh its okay")
    
    
list_o_fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
    
eval_list = (lambda x=list_o_fruits: evaluate_fruit(x))
    
eval_list()
```

**Output:**

```
Good choice!
Meh its okay
Meh its okay
```

When running the code above, the output is as expected however PyCharm doesn't like it when I pass a list/dictionary (mutable) into the lambda function. To my understanding, it is bad practice to declare a list/dictionary as a function's default value and that makes sense. However what if I only read the content of the list/dictionary and not alter it in any way inside the function, would it be acceptable then?

Either way, what would be a better approach to declare my lambda function with a list/dictionary argument? The web has suggested a workaround for passing a mutable as a default in a 'normal' function by setting the default to 'None' then using an if-statement:

```py
def evaluate_fruits(fruits=None):
    if fruits is None:
        fruits = []
    .
    .
    .
```

I could possibly utilize this concept for lambda function too but then that would make the function inconveniently long and redundant as I would have to create an if-statement condition for each generated lambda from `evaluate_fruits()` (it kind of defeats the purpose of using lambda).

An example would be if I had five lists (`list_o_fruits1`, `list_o_fruits2`, ..., `list_o_fruits5`) and I wanted to created a lambda function for each of them (`eval_list1`, `eval_list2`, ..., `eval_list3`) from `evaluate_fruits()`.

Could I be missing something?

Comment: Is there a reason `list_of_fruits` needs to be mutable?

Comment: Just ignore it, you aren't going to mutate your lambda, and if you are, it shouldn't make a difference

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Well I want to pass multiple values into the function together so I bundled them up in a list. I guess I could add them one by one as function arguments but my real `list_o_fruits` contains over 10 elements :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your only requirement is to bundle several elements together into one object, and that object doesn't need to be mutable, use a tuple instead of a list. Tuples provide all the same behavior of lists except for modification of their elements. To be exact, mutable elements can still be mutated, but elements of the tuple cannot be assigned, added, or removed, and the tuple itself is considered an immutable data structure. The syntax for constructing a tuple is the same as a list, just with parentheses instead of square brackets:

```
# Immutable container with immutable elements, perfectly fine to use as a default argument
tuple_o_fruits = ("Apple", "Banana", "Orange")
```

Python's lack of generic enforceable const-correctness is one of the few things that really irks me about the language. The standard solution is to use builtin immutable datatypes like `tuple` in place of mutable ones like `list`. The immutable form of `set` is `frozenset`, for example. Many common builtin types such as `str`, `int`, and `float` are only available in immutable form. `bytes` is an interesting case because the immutable form is better known than its mutable alternative, `bytearray`. The most prominent builtin mutable type that lacks an immutable alternative is `dict` ([but it's not hard to make your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703599/what-would-a-frozen-dict-be)).

So, the real answer to "how do I avoid warnings about mutable default arguments" is, 9 times out of 10, to not use a mutable object, because immutable alternative are generally readily available. This should be sufficient for your case.

Answer (score 0):

From this link: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html

> Passing mutable lists or dictionaries as default arguments to a
> function can have unforeseen consequences. Usually when a programmer
> uses a list or dictionary as the default argument to a function, the
> programmer wants the program to create a new list or dictionary every
> time that the function is called. However, this is not what Python
> does. The first time that the function is called, Python creates a
> persistent object for the list or dictionary. Every subsequent time
> the function is called, Python uses that same persistent object that
> was created from the first call to the function.