# Groupby lists in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0':[[0,1],[1,0,0],[1,0],[1,0],[2,0]],
                   'col1':[5,4,3,2,1]})
```

ie:

```
        col0  col1
0     [0, 1]     5
1  [1, 0, 0]     4
2     [1, 0]     3
3     [1, 0]     2
4     [2, 0]     1
```

I would like to group by values in `col0`, and sum `col1` values in the same group. I do:

```
df.groupby('col0').col1.sum()
```

but this gives `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. I do then:

```
df.groupby(df.col0.apply(frozenset)).col1.sum()
```

which gives:

```
col0
(0, 1)    14
(0, 2)     1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Ie lists were converted into sets (`frozenset`s to be exact), and then groupbyed. The number of elements and order of them did not matter (ie `[1,0]` and `[0,1]` belongs to the same group, so does `[1,0]` and `[1,0,0]`)

**If order and number of elements also matter, how do I groupby then?**

Desired output of groupbying `col0` and summing `col1` of above dataframe:

```
col0
[0, 1]     5
[1,0,0]    4
[1, 0]     5
[2,0]      1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: frozenset is to set what tuple is to list, use tuples ;)

Comment: @mozway That's a very enlightening way of putting it, thanks.

Comment: @mozway  What is for dicts which is frozenset for set & tuple for list?

Comment: I don't think it exists, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703599/what-would-a-frozen-dict-be), but usually what matters most are the keys. So I guess a frozenset/tuple of keys, or of key/value pairs ;)

Comment: Great, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tuple` is immutable, can contain duplicates and maintains the order.

```
df['col0'] = df['col0'].apply(tuple)
df.groupby('col0', sort=False).sum() # sort=False for original order of col0 
#            col1
# col0           
# (0, 1)        5
# (1, 0, 0)     4
# (1, 0)        5
# (2, 0)        1
```

Comment: That would be my answer as well. After grouping you can easily revert back to list if needed

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to string just for grouping:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0':[[0,1],[1,0,0],[1,0],[1,0],[2,0]],
                   'col1':[5,4,3,2,1]})
df.groupby(df['col0'].astype(str)).sum()
```