# Python - Handling of dictionaries in classes

Tags: python, dictionary, class

Here's the question - When a class has a dictionary, that is initialized in the **init** method, the manner in which it is initialized can lead the dictionary to be shared between all instances.

Here is a test code that shows different ways to initialize a dictionary:

```
class testDic:
        def __init__(self,name,aDic={},**kwargs):
                self.name=name
                self.aDic=aDic
                self.anotherDic={}
                self.kwDic=kwargs.get('dic',{})

        def print(self):
                print(self.name,' aDic : ',self.aDic,' anotherDic: ',self.anotherDic," kwDic : ",self.kwDic)

print("dics initialised: ")
obj1=testDic('obj1',aDic={'key1':1})
obj2=testDic('obj2',aDic={'key2':2})
obj1.print()
obj2.print()
print("aDic address ",obj1.name,id(obj1.aDic))
print("aDic address ",obj2.name,id(obj2.aDic))

print("dics updated: ")
obj3=testDic('obj3')
obj4=testDic('obj4')
obj3.aDic.update({'key3':3})
obj4.aDic.update({'key4':4})
obj3.anotherDic.update({'anotherKey3':3})
obj4.anotherDic.update({'anotherKey4':4})
obj3.kwDic.update({'kwKey3':3})
obj4.kwDic.update({'kwKey4':4})

obj3.print()
obj4.print()
print("aDic address ",obj3.name,id(obj3.aDic))
print("aDic address ",obj4.name,id(obj4.aDic))
print("anotherDic address ",obj3.name,id(obj3.anotherDic))
print("anotherDic address ",obj4.name,id(obj4.anotherDic))
print("kwDic address ",obj3.name,id(obj3.kwDic))
print("kwDic address ",obj4.name,id(obj4.kwDic))
```

The outcome of this code is as follows:

```
dics initialised: 
obj1  aDic :  {'key1': 1}  anotherDic:  {}  kwDic :  {}
obj2  aDic :  {'key2': 2}  anotherDic:  {}  kwDic :  {}
aDic address  obj1 140281810029952
aDic address  obj2 140281809223296
dics updated: 
obj3  aDic :  {'key3': 3, 'key4': 4}  anotherDic:  {'anotherKey3': 3}  kwDic :  {'kwKey3': 3}
obj4  aDic :  {'key3': 3, 'key4': 4}  anotherDic:  {'anotherKey4': 4}  kwDic :  {'kwKey4': 4}
aDic address  obj3 140281810030016
aDic address  obj4 140281810030016
anotherDic address  obj3 140281809318208
anotherDic address  obj4 140281809318720
kwDic address  obj3 140281809318464
kwDic address  obj4 140281809318592
```

As the output of the code shows, there's an issue with aDic, that is initialized this way:

```
__init__(self, aDic={}):
    self.aDic=aDic
```

1. if an existing dictionary is passed, all is fine (see output for obj1,obj2)
2. if however **no** existing dictionary is passed, the same dictionary is shared between all instances, as shows:

- **aDic address  obj3 140281810030016**
- **aDic address  obj4 140281810030016**

and

- **obj3  aDic :  {'key3': 3, 'key4': 4}**
- **obj4  aDic :  {'key3': 3, 'key4': 4}**

There is no issue with anotherDic or kwDic.

What's happening here??
Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/2442804

Answer (score 0):

You should not use default mutable values. Instead, use one of the following methods (the first one is recommended):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a_dict=None):
        self._a_dict = a_dict or {}
```

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a_dict=frozendict()):
        self._a_dict = dict(a_dict)
```

Note: You should use [frozendict](https://pypi.org/project/frozendict/) library or `MappingProxyType` for `frozendict` (visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638022/6628488) for more information).

Comment: An empty fronzendict won't be very useful…