# does Python support constants that are enforced by the interpreter?

Tags: python, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating constant in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/creating-constant-in-python)

Does Python support constants that are enforced by the interpreter?  For example: integer constants.  How about a programmer defined enumerated type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating constant in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/creating-constant-in-python) and a [lot of others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+constants).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. If you want something to be constant then just refrain from modifying it.

Comment: +1 or perhaps if that's too hard then one could just switch to Java!

Comment: +1: If you have a `some_constant = ...` line of code, that is a problem; those lines are really easy to spot.   Further, if you using ALL_UPPERCASE, pylint will warn you.

Comment: Since Python 3.4 there is Enum (https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)