# What are constants and literal constants?

Tags: python, constants, literals

I'm learning Python and I am confused with the constants and literal constants. What are they? For what kind of purpose do we use them? What is the difference from the normal variable?

I'm a true beginner. As beginner, I can say I know nothing about the programming world. For example, I don't know what an expression is and vice versa.

I have been learning the Python language using the *"A byte of python"* book and somewhere in the book I came across a section which talks about literals and constants.I share the section there:

> 5.2. Literal Constants
>
> An example of a literal constant is a number like 5 , 1.23 , or a
> string like 'This is a string' or "It's a string!" .
>
> It is called a literal because it is literal - you use its value
> literally. The number 2 always represents itself and nothing else - it
> is a constant because its value cannot be changed. Hence, all these
> are referred to as literal constants.

Where it says, *"it is called literal because it is literal-you use the it's value literally"*, I just don't get this part. What is the book trying to say that we use the value literally? Another vague point is that the number 2 is a constant because its value cannot be changed. How is it possible? We can change it, like:

```
stack = 2
stack = 3
```

First, I assigned the number 2 to the stack then I changed the value of the stack (which is that number 2 that the book is claiming it is a constant so it cannot be changed) and assigned the number 3 to it. So, I easily changed the value of the number 2. I am really confused, if you didn't get my point ,please tell me so I can give more examples.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Python doesn't have constants - variables with `UPPERCASE` names are constant by convention, but that isn't enforced anywhere.

Comment: @arshajii I have edited the post and given example.

Comment: You did not change the value of 2. You changed what the name `Stack` was bound to, from the value 2 to the value 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Answer after OP's edit**

A literal constant is an actual literal value; I know the word literal confuses you but an example might make it clearer. If you type the following in the REPL:

```
>>> 2
2
>>> 'hello'
'hello'
```

`2` and `hello` are actual literal constants and contrary to what you think, you can't change their value (well, you can, as a beginner, it's best to not know about that). When you have:

```
stack = 2
stack = 3
```

You are first assigning the constant literal (though, honestly, don't worry about what it's called, it's the number 2) to `stack`. So, *the name `stack` is pointing to the value `2`*. Then, by saying `stack = 3`, you are ***not*** changing the value `2`; *you are now making the name `stack` to point to another value, `3`*.

For what it's worth, "constant literal" sounds complicated; just think of values like `2` or `'John'` etc. as what they are. And with regards to actual constants (in programming constants are referred to variables that cannot be changed after assignment), that concept doesn't really exist in Python. A constant is when, for instance, you say `stack = 2` but then you cannot ever change what `stack` is pointing to or you'll get an error. In Python, this concept does not exist.

**Original Answer:**

For starters, I recommend you read [The story of None, True and False (and an explanation of literals, keywords and builtins thrown in)](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/story-of-none-true-false.html) by Guido:

> A literal, on the other hand, is an element of an expression that describes a constant value. Examples of literals are numbers (e.g. 42, 3.14, or 1.6e-10) and strings (e.g. "Hello, world"). Literals are recognized by the parser, and the exact rules for how literals are parsed are often quite subtle.

As for "constants", you cannot declare a variables as "true constants" in Python. There are a [Built-in Constants](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/constants.html) like `True` and `False` and `None` in Python but even they are not"true constants" in Python 2.X as they can be assigned to point to another value:

```
True = False
if True:
    print 'Hey' 
else:
    print 'WAAAT!'
```

I hope this helps. If not, please edit your questions and give an example of what you mean exactly by Constants and Literal Constants.

Note: `True` and `False` and the like are keywords in Python 3.x, so if you say `True = False`, the interpreter will raise `SyntaxError: assignment to keyword`.

Comment: IIRC `True` and `False` are "true" constants in Python 3…

Comment: Fixed that. Thanks. They are keywords and assigning to them now raises a `SyntaxError: assignment to keyword`

Comment: @s16h  I really couldn't get the slightest idea from your answer.I have edited my post.

Comment: Let me know if the newly added answer is better please. If not, I may be able to make it simpler; perhaps take another step back.

Comment: @s16h: Thank you,it was perfect.But if there is nothing exist named Constant in Python,then why some people say there is ? check the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/creating-constant-in-python

Comment: Notice the first thing the selected answer in the link you're provided says: "No there is not. You cannot declare a variable or value as constant in Python.". You can use the convention of naming a variable in all caps so that the person using the variables knows not to change its value but that's just a convention; there is no language construct to stop a person from changing it.

Comment: @s16h you said: _2 and hello are actual literal constants and contrary to what you think, you can't change their value (well, you can, as a beginner, it's best to not know about that)_. How exactly can one change the value of `2` and `Hello`?

Comment: @MariusMucenicu it can be done by finding out the address of where constant literal resides in memory and then changing its value, it can be done using `ctypes` in python.