# Make a python list constant and uneditable

Tags: python, constants

I've got a code:

```
def constant(f):
    def fset(self, value):
        raise SyntaxError( "You can't change a constant!" )
    def fget(self):
        return f(self)
    return property(fget, fset)

class A( object ):
    def __init__( self, a_list ):
        super( A, self ).__init__()
        self.__data = a_list[:]
    @constant
    def data( self ):
        return self.__data
```

I would like to make self.__data accessible, but unchangeable and uneditable from outside of the class. I can't simply change it to a tuple, cause I would like it to be easy to change for methods inside the class. The solution that I presented above doesn't work, when someone modifies the list:

```
>>> a = A( range(5) )
>>> a.data = []
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
SyntaxError: You can't change a constant! # it works
>>> a.data[0]=6                           # it doesn't work
>>> a.data
[6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Do you know any nice solution of my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/creating-constant-in-python

Comment: It's python, there is always a way to change it. If people use your code incorrectly it will break and it's on them. Just make sure you have some good documentation stating why you shouldn't change it.

Comment: So you want it to appear to be externally, but actually internally not be? Why? *"We're all consenting adults, here"* - just a single leading underscore on the list should suffice.

Comment: The other option is to make `data` `return self.__data[:]`, then if whatever receives it does mutate it that doesn't matter.

Comment: Consider raising a custom exception rather than a `SyntaxError` as it's not really a syntax problem if someone tries to use your object in a way you don't like.

Comment: Why not `self.__data = tuple(a_list)`?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Because the idea is to retain mutability internally. The other class methods are supposed to be able to change the internal list, but nothing outside the class. (This is fundamentally about a sort of encapsulation that Python just does not support.)

Comment: What about the case where the elements of the list are mutable, for example they're lists or dictionaries?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought there is a smart solution, that allows encapsulation. Your solution (return copy of the list) will still fail, when the elements of list are mutable, as Cristian Ciupitu said (but using a tuple in the situation doesn't change anything, you can still modify a mutable elements of the tuple). But maybe copy.deepcopy() will work, although it is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

**Provide some hints what shouldn't be changed but let people change it if they really want.**

If you want uneditable `list` use `tuple`. Use leading underscore for extra "security".

There's always way to change <strike>list</strike> anything in Python. Even if I had to break into your house, steal your code and then change it - it's possible.

```
_change_this_and_I_will_kill_you_with_my_axe = [] # never use this name
```

If you eg. return list and don't want it modified return copy but there still **will** be way to modify it.

```
return my_list[:]
```

Comment: "Even if I had to break into your house, steal your code, and change it." If changing the source code counts, I don't think your tuple suggestion is going to fare any better. :P

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Yes, you could change it to `list` and mutate that. :) In case it isn't obvious the point isn't to prevent your code from changing but to provide hints - _maybe you shouldn't change my variable `pi` to 42, but feel free to do so if you really want._

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a View-class that implements all the read operations for the list. Of course, there would still be a way to access the internal list, there is no was to prevent that.

```
class ListView(object):
  def __init__(self, list_):
    self._list = list_
  def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self._list[index]
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'ListView(%r)' % self._list
  def index(self, value):
    return self._list.index(value)
  # and so on
```

(sent from a mobile device)

Comment: You can do this, but be prepared to write a couple dozen redundant methods that do one of two things: defer to the internal list (as each method you've shown does), or raise an exception complaining about an invalid op.

Comment: I would suggest using `collections.abc.Sequence` as the base class. All you need do is define `__getitem__` and `__len__` and the `abc` will do the rest for you.