# How do you know what a constant is?

Tags: python, constants

Would `student_name` be a constant or not?

```
student_name = ""

while len(student_name) > 1:
    int(input(User input name of student and store this in variable student_name))
```

Comment: No, it would not be a constant since the value is presumably changing... though it is a bit unclear because the code you show doesn't actually change the value, it just _implys_ that the value should change in the while loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a constant in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/how-do-i-create-a-constant-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you would call a constant. Python has immutable objects. like strings. Remember that in Python variables are basically labels on objects. So if you write

```
x = 'foo'
```

the label `x` is used for the immutable string `'foo'`. If you then were to do

```
x = 'bar'
```

you haven't changed the string, you've just hung the label on a different string.

But immutable *objects* are not what we generally think of as constants. In Python a constant could be thought of as an immutable *label*; a variable (label) that cannot be changed once it is assigned.

Until recently, Python didn't really have those. By *convention*, an all-uppercase name signals that it shouldn't be changed. But this isn't enforced by the language.

But since Python 3.4 (and also backported to 2.7) we have the [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) module that defines different kinds of enumeration classes (singletons really). An enumeration can basically be used as group of constants.

Here is an example where a function to compare files returns an enum;

```
from enum import IntEnum
from hashlib import sha256
import os

# File comparison result
class Cmp(IntEnum):
    differ = 0  # source and destination are different
    same = 1  # source and destination are identical
    nodest = 2  # destination doesn't exist
    nosrc = 3  # source doesn't exist


def compare(src, dest):
    """
    Compare two files.

    Arguments
        src: Path of the source file.
        dest: Path of the destination file.

    Returns:
        Cmp enum
    """
    xsrc, xdest = os.path.exists(src), os.path.exists(dest)
    if not xsrc:
        return Cmp.nosrc
    if not xdest:
        return Cmp.nodest
    with open(src, 'rb') as s:
        csrc = sha256(s.read()).digest()
    if xdest:
        with open(dest, 'rb') as d:
            cdest = sha256(d.read()).digest()
    else:
        cdest = b''
    if csrc == cdest:
        return Cmp.same
    return Cmp.differ
```

This saves you having to look up what the return value of `compare` actually means every time you use it.

You cannot change *existing* attributes of the `enum` after it has been defined. There is one surprise here; you can add new attributes later, and those can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. You cannot declare a variable or value as constant in Python. Just don't change it.

If you are in a class, the equivalent would be:

```
class Foo(object):
    CONST_NAME = "Name"
```

if not, it is just

```
CONST_NAME = "Name"
```

The following code snippet might help you [Link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/?in=user-97991) .