# How do I create a constant in AutoHotkey?

Tags: constants, autohotkey

Many languages have methods for declaring constant values that can't be changed once created.

```java
public static final int MAX_TIME = 25; // Java
const int MAX_TIME = 25;               // C++
const MAX_TIME = 25;                   // JavaScript
```

Is there an equivalent way to declare constants in AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use a function.

```
MAX_TIME() {
    return 25
}
MsgBox % MAX_TIME()
```

Attempting to redefine the function produces `Error: Duplicate function definition`.

```
MAX_TIME() {
    return 25
}
MsgBox % MAX_TIME()
MAX_TIME() {
    return 22
}
```

Note that even after the function has been defined, creating a value with `MAX_TIME = 20` is still allowed, so be consistent and always use the function instead of a variable.

Two other approaches are described at https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/90774-is-it-possible-to-create-constant/.  The first is to simply use a variable and remember not to change it.  This seems to be the preferred approach.

The second is to use a class property to store the constant, and override `__Set()` so that the value cannot be changed.

Python works pretty much the same way.  See [How do I create a constant in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/how-do-i-create-a-constant-in-python)

Comment: Upvoted for "simply use a variable and remember not to change it" - naming it in ALL_CAPS is the usual mnemonic. Only public libraries would need more than this.

Comment: @Dewi Morgan: Agreed, that is generally the best approach.  My answer should have emphasized that.

Answer (score 0):

I simply create constants as variables with names starting with an underscore(_). Easy to remember not to change any such variable.