# sys.modules[__name__] = _classname(). What does it actually do?

Tags: python

I am reading [this piece of code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/?in=user-97991) by Alex Martelli mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/how-do-i-create-a-constant-in-python/2682752). I understand that `sys.modules[__name__]` tells you what module you are currently at, but this line of code at the end of his `constant.py` really confuses me. What is the meaning and the point of having such a statement that declares the current module by the end of the file?

```
# Put in const.py...:
class _const:
    class ConstError(TypeError): pass
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        if self.__dict__.has_key(name):
            raise self.ConstError, "Can't rebind const(%s)"%name
        self.__dict__[name]=value
import sys
sys.modules[__name__]=_const() #this I don't understand
# that's all -- now any client-code can
import const
```

Basically, my question is that in my opinion this line of code does not do anything; am I understanding it wrong?
Since in Python you don't have to put class definitions in separate files, I argue that I don't really need two modules unless I want to reuse the class "const." Then in this case `sys.moldules[__name__]=_const()` is not necessary either... Am I understanding it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is binding an instance to the module. So when you do `import const`, you actually get an instance of the class `_const`.

This allows you to call methods on it. Like, for example, the `__setattr__`, where in this case it checks that you only bind a variable once.

Comment: So without that line of code, doing `import const` will run that python module, instead of getting an instance of the class then?

Comment: yes, `import const` will behave like a normal package import, with a class called `_const` defined inside. And given the underscore prefix, it would not be imported through `from const import *` (from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables))

Answer (score 2):

This is described by Guido van Rossum as a *hack* that is *sometimes* recommended:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2012-May/014969.html

```py
# foo.py
import sys

class Foo:
    def funct1(self, <args>): <code>
    def funct2(self, <args>): <code>

sys.modules[__name__] = Foo()
```

> This works because the import machinery is actively enabling this
> hack, and as its final step pulls the actual module out of
> sys.modules, after loading it. (This is no accident. The hack was
> proposed long ago and we decided we liked enough to support it in the
> import machinery.)

> You can easily override `__getattr__` / `__getattribute__` / `__setattr__`
> this way. It also makes "subclassing" the module a little easier
> (although accessing the class to be used as a base class is a little
> tricky: you'd have to use `foo.__class__`). But of course the kind of
> API that Greg was griping about would never be implemented this way,
> so that's fairly useless. And if you were designing a module as an
> inheritable class right from the start you're much better off just
> using a class instead of the above hack.