# How to allow a class attribute to be accessible from the module global context in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, enums, attributes, global

I defined an enum class and would like to be able to use its attributes without need to access it through class name. I mean:

```
class MyEnum:
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    ...

if MyEnum.ONE == 1:
    "Typic use"
if TWO == 2:
    "My desire"
```

Is there a way to do this?

---

In my specific context, I'm calculating points externality of a window through [Cohen–Sutherland algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm), so I have the following code:

```
class Externality:
    INSIDE = 0
    LEFT = 1
    RIGTH = 2
    BELLOW = 4
    ABOVE = 8
```

```
# And at some point:
((x, y), externality) = actual

if not Externality.INSIDE in externality:
    del cohen_sutherland_list[0]
```

So, the needed of express Enum's name to access its items make the `if` statement (and the whole code) a little more verbose and redundant.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You should use `MyEnum.TWO`.

Comment: It's basically to improve readability, since in the archive context I use it the meaning of its items are pretty obvious and, in the algorithms, the name is used to define the variables that store this values is the same Emun name, so it gets a little redundant

Comment: "... the name is used to define the variables that store this values is the same Emun name" Could you please post some code for context? I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I included my specific context description in the question

Comment: Too late! Drat. You have got an answer. :-) In addition, [this post is an interesting read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/how-do-i-create-a-constant-in-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first:  inherit from `Enum`.

---

Like everything in Python, all you need to do is assign the names:

```
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2

ONE = MyEnum.ONE
TWO = MyEnum.TWO
```

That can get annoying fast, so a helper function would be nice:

```
def export_enum(enum_cls, env):
    for member in enum_cls:
        env[member.name] = member
```

and in use:

```
>>> export_enum(MyEnum, globals())
>>> TWO
<MyEnum.TWO: 2>
```

If you use [`aenum`](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/)<sup>1</sup> the `export()` function is already available, and can be used as a decorator:

```
from aenum import Enum, export

@export(globals())
class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: The `aenum` decorator option is a pretty nice solution and I've already put it in use, +1. Thanks!