# How constant is tf.constant?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

According to other StackOverFlow questions, you cannot change `tf.constant`, but when I do this it runs perfectly:

```
>>>c = tf.constant([2])
>>>c += 1
>>>print(c)
[3]
```

Why is that?

Comment: constant is to be seen as in a mathematical sense (in contrast to a variable for example that you need to find or optimize) not in a informatic sense. It is not a `const int `, or whatever, if you know the C language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still a constant in the sense that you cannot `assign` to it. Running `c += 1` just change the object that `c` points to like `c = c + 1`.

```
c = tf.constant(2)
print(id(c)) # "Address" is 140481630446312 (for my run)
c += 1
print(id(c)) # "Address" is different
```

but this fails everytime: `c.assign(2)`

This is not a limitation  of Tensorflow, but of Python itself. Since it's not compiled, we can't check for constants. The best you can do these days is use a type hint (Python 3.6+) to signify to IDEs and optional static typecheckers that you don't want a variable to be reassigned. [See this answer for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2682752/2174693)

Answer (score 2):

The original `c` is constant and remains unchanged. You loose reference to it by creating a new tensor with the same name `c` that equals to the old value of `c` plus `1`.