# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary

I want to create a constant variable whose structure looking like this:

```
 const example_order_3_lines = [
  {
    order_id: 111_222_333,
    line_items:[
      {
        title: 'cookie',
        quantity: 5,
        space: 0.5,
      },
      {
        title: 'md meal',
        quantity: 3,
        space: 2.0,
      },
      {
        title: 'lg meal',
        quantity: 4,
        space: 3.0,
      },
      {
        title: 'soup',
        quantity: 2,
        space: 2.5,
      },
      {
        title: 'apple pie',
        quantity: 3,
        space: 1,
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

but when I run that cell I got this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-60-44a3630eacc1>", line 1
    const example_order_3_lines = [
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

when i remove const from the variable it give this error:

```
   NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-a12c8a34587f> in <module>
      1 example_order_3_lines = [
      2  {
----> 3    order_id: 111_222_333,
      4    line_items:[
      5      {

NameError: name 'order_id' is not defined
```

Can someone help me what is wrong in this.

There is my main function:

```
function __main__() {
  const BAG_SIZE = 4;
  const results = solve(example_order_3_lines, BAG_SIZE);
  console.log('results: ', results[0].bags.length, JSON.stringify(results[0].bags, null, 2));
}
__main__();
```

The main task is that I want to create a function 'solve' where it use 'quantity' and 'space' to find minimum bags require for packing. I want to use knapsack method for this.

Comment: try to remove const :)

Comment: Who told you that Python has `const`?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/how-do-i-create-a-constant-in-python) to realize there is no const in python

Comment: also 111_222_333 it's pretty strange

Comment: I update my question where I mention what happen when I remove const from the code.

Comment: nice one @dejdej

Comment: It give me same error if  "111_222_333" is string.

Comment: Where did you get this? This is not a valid Python syntax.

Comment: @SarlaDevi try to understand the fundamental of Python first, what do you want to do exactly? create an anonymous object? JSON object?

Comment: This looks like you copy-pasted a bunch of some other language into a Python program and expected it to run. (Maybe Typescript or something.)

Comment: I change the question

Comment: @dejdej: That part's actually valid Python.

Comment: When your friend said, "change it so nobody thinks it's a copy-paste" @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: You've already asked this question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64062467/algorithim-pack-n-bags-for-orders-problem

Comment: The extra stuff you added is even more obviously not Python. Why are you trying to run this as Python in the first place?

Comment: sorry to all this is javascript version. I think that is a python.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove const as Shahroozevsky already mentioned. And a dictinary consists of key:value pairs. The key must be immutable. Which means you can use strings, numbers or tuples as dictionary keys.

line_items:[
{
"title": 'cookie',
"quantity": 5,
"space": 0.5
},

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Answer (score 3):

A valid Python example should look something like this:

```
example_order_3_lines = [
    {
        "order_id": "111_222_333",
        "line_items": [
            {
                "title": 'cookie',
                "quantity": 5,
                "space": 0.5,
            },
            {
                "title": 'md meal',
                "quantity": 3,
                "space": 2.0,
            },
            {
                "title": 'lg meal',
                "quantity": 4,
                "space": 3.0,
            },
            {
                "title": 'soup',
                "quantity": 2,
                "space": 2.5,
            },
            {
                "title": 'apple pie',
                "quantity": 3,
                "space": 1,
            }
        ],
    },
]

print(example_order_3_lines[0]['line_items'][0]['title'])
```

Output: `cookie`