# Can I use Pydantic models with constant variable names and later referencing them using their value?

Tags: python, pydantic

Can I use pydantic models using constant names and later referencing them using their value?

An example is worth more than a thousand words:

Is there a way to do this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

COLUMN_MEAN = "mean"
COLUMN_LENGTH = "length"

class Item(BaseModel):
    COLUMN_MEAN: float
    COLUMN_LENGTH: int
```

But later, when using the model, doing it like this:

```py
Item(mean=2.1, length=10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not use const in python, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/how-do-i-create-a-constant-in-python/2682752).

Buf if you want another name for `BaseModel` field, can use `alias`.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Final

COLUMN_MEAN = "mean"
COLUMN_LENGTH = "length"

class Item(BaseModel):
    COLUMN_MEAN: float = Field(alias=COLUMN_MEAN)
    COLUMN_LENGTH: int = Field(alias=COLUMN_LENGTH)

Item(mean=2.1, length=10)
```

output in jupyter:

```
Item(COLUMN_MEAN=2.1, COLUMN_LENGTH=10)
```

Comment: I know this way, however, then you cannot do later `item.mean` you need to convert it to JSON with the  `byalias`flag