# Python constant uuid token in class (property does not work)

Tags: python, properties, constants

I need a class that remembers its constant token (uuid). When I use the property decorator as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45068730/14900791), **the `property` will prevent the `uuid` function from changing, but not the value**:

```py
from uuid import uuid4

class Tokenizer:
    @property
    def token(self):
        return uuid4().hex

t = Tokenizer()

print(t.token)
print(t.token)
```

This prints diffrent tokens, so how can I achieve the **constant token so the output will be the same**, without passing token to the class as argument?

Edit: `t.__token` can by changed but does not affect `t.token`. Do you know why?

```py
from uuid import uuid4

class Tokenizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__token = uuid4().hex
    
    @property
    def token(self):
        return self.__token

t = Tokenizer()

print(t.token)
print(t.token)
```

Comment: Do you want a single UUID for the *class*, or a separate UUID for each *instance* of the class?

Comment: I want separate uuid for each instance of the class, so the `t1` and `t2` are diffrent. `t1 = Tokenizer().token; t2 = Tokenizer().token`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is basically done here is I am creating a token if it does not exist and if the instance of class has already set the token, then we will be returning the existing token.

The __token variable in the updated code is not modifiable because it is a class-level variable, and it is defined with double underscores as __token. This makes it a private variable that cannot be accessed or modified directly from outside the class.

```
from uuid import uuid4

class Tokenizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__token = uuid4().hex
    
    @property
    def token(self):
        return self.__token

t = Tokenizer()

print(t.token)
print(t.token)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I would prefer to use a method in which the token cannot be overwritten (`__token` can be overwritten)

Comment: I thought `class Tokenizer: token = property(lambda self: uuid4().hex)` will work but doesn't.

Comment: See the updated answer. Now we have remove the set_token method which could have been used to update the token. Since __token is defined with __ it cannot be modified outside class.

Comment: @SanjayShahi It *can*, but anyone doing so proceeds at their own risk.

Comment: Your previous approach was better, as now *every* token shares the same UUID.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `t.__token` can by changed but does not affect `t.token`. Do you know why?

Comment: @Jurakin `Tokenizer.__token` and `t.__token` are two entirely separate attributes (the former a class attribute, the latter an instance attribute). You can't really stop anyone from changing either of them, but the name strongly suggests that one *shouldn't*. `Tokenizer.token`, on the other hand, is a *property*, so assigning to `t.token` triggers the descriptor protocol, and `Tokenizer.token` is defined to raise an error if anyone attempts to do so.

Comment: @chepner My apologies, I posted an edit to Sanja's answer (I simplified the answer), but it was not approved. See my question when I included the change. You are correct that `tokenizer.__token` is not the same as `t.__token`, but I was referring to my edit.

Comment: @Jurakin OK, yes, that's what I would do. Using a property as the public interface to a private attribute is a common pattern.