# Could I set a variable readonly in Python?

Tags: python, variables, readonly

I want to set a object in module be **readonly** and shared in common.
Like follow situation:

```py
# configure.py
with open("config.yaml","r") as f:
    config = yaml.load(f)
```

and `configure.py` will be used by other scripts. The **config** object shoud be readonly and fixed.

```py
# data.py
from configure import config
some_operation( config )
# ....
```

```py
# main.py
from configure import config
config["attr"] = "erroneously_setting"
some_operation( config )
```

I worry that **config** object would be erroneously modified by other scripts.

Could I set a variable readonly ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`final\` keyword equivalent for variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802578/final-keyword-equivalent-for-variables-in-python)

Comment: @Alvi15 Note that the `final` decorator is only a type hint for your IDE. It won't stop people from actually modifying the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't make an attribute read-only in Python, but you can hide the implementation details and use properties to expose attributes:

```
class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = 1

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo


if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Config()
    print("Foo is", config.foo)
    config.foo = 1
```

this will print

```
Foo is 1
```

then

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    config.foo = 1
AttributeError: can't set attribute 'foo'
```

Edit: Here is an example of an immutable dictionary per OP's clarification:

```
class ImmutableDict(dict):
    def set(self):
        raise NotImplemented()

    def __setitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise RuntimeError("This is an immutable dictionary")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_dict = ImmutableDict({"foo": 1, "bar": 2})
    print(my_dict["foo"])
    my_dict["foo"] = 3
```

This should print:

```
1
```

then

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    my_dict["foo"] = 3
    raise RuntimeError("This is an immutable dictionary")
RuntimeError: This is an immutable dictionary
```

Comment: The problem is that a config object loaded from a YAML file often contains nested containers, which can still be freely mutated even through a class like above.

Comment: @blhsing It is possible to create immutable variants of those data structures if it is strictly necessary, but fair point.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks, my question should be  "how to create immutable dictionary". Simply use property of class should is not demand.

Comment: @SiuolLee That's not too hard, you should simply override `__setitem__`. See my updated answer for a trivial example.